# How to implement Email validation using Apex?

Tags: security, oracle-apex

I'm working on Apex and I'm trying to implement an email validation process. When the user subscribes he will receive a mail with a link to validate his account.

The way I'm planning to do it is :

In the table Users, create two columns that are filled with unique **random** 20 character codes Column1, Column 2 that are 20-character long;

For example

- Column 1 : **sd7f54xcze4aze654SDF**
- Column 2 : **q4fg4apu8ty9cf3q21cq**

Then create a **public** page with two hidden items; Let's say  :

- Field 1
- Field 2

In the email there will be a link to open the page and fill out these two **non protected** fields:

apex:

```
www.domain.com/f?p=App:MyPageID:Field1,Field2:Code1,Code2
```

The user will then click submit.

An internal process will search in the table Users and check if there is a new user whom Column 1 & 2 correspond to these two code.

If it's the case, then validate the account, else throw error.

Is this implementation safe please ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why 2 fields and values?  A single 40 character string would be equally secure.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add prevent URL tampering by adding checksum in your url and in page level.

Comment: I upvoted yeserday, but actually this isn't possible in a link that has been sent out in an email.  Checksums are specific to a session.   Assuming you meant an APEX checksum rather than something bespoke...?

Comment: No i'm talking about apex checksum. this will normally work. by using apex_util.prepare_url . eg:    apex_util.prepare_url( p_url =>'https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=&APP_ID.:&APP_PAGE_ID.:&SESSION.::::P6_ID_JOB_OFFER:&P6_ID_JOB_OFFER.',p_checksum_type => 3) Apex do calculation based on your url parameter and generate checksum. then when user click on the link , apex verify if checksum are same. but i notice that apex_util.prepare_url has a problem the procedure do not generate checksum i don't know why? https://community.oracle.com/thread/3979483

Comment: Sorry, seems I was wrong!  I thought APEX checksums were session-specific, but it appears not after all.